# ¿Qué tan aceptable es "es como [algo]" como sustituto de "[se] parece [algo]"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

Según Google Translate, "It's a little like [something]" se traduce como "Es un poco como [algo]." ¿Es correcto? Además, ¿es también aceptable decir "Comó es un poco como [algo]"?

Incluso si esto se considera una forma "divertida" de decirlo, si es gramaticalmente correcto, me gustaría usarlo como un punto de partida para que sea simple y fácil de recordar para mis alumnos. Más adelante, planeo agregar la frase "[se] parece a [algo]".

¿Qué les parece a ustedes?

Comment: Lo siento pero tu pregunta tenía bastantes errores gramaticales y ni siquiera corrigiéndolos la termino de entender. Todas las frases que planteás son prácticamente lo mismo, pero ninguna es "divertida". Por otro lado, sin ofender tu pregunta parece una tomada de pelos. Más aun cuando afirmás ser profesor.

Comment: Google translate no es siempre fiable. Y eso: "Comó es un poco como [algo]"? no es español.

Comment: @Lambie Samuel Muldoon #4

Comment: @tac Ah si, cambió de nombre. Fui la primera a señalar ese tio y nadie ,me hizo caso. Ahora, parece que se están fiando más. No entiendo lo que esa persona intenta hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una sutil diferencia.

> Es como una estrella

Si no hay ninguna otra especificación, refiere más a la forma.

> Es un poco como una estrella

> Se parece a una estrella

Si no hay ninguna especificación, puede referir a la forma o a cualquier otra cualidad, tal como el brillo. Quizás no sean afirmaciones tan exactas como afirmar que **ES** como el objeto señalado.

No obstante cualquier opción es válida.

Comment: Tengo dudas de que sea cierta la distinción en cuanto al uso que hacés, parece ser más bien de orden personal. Yo no veo que se cumpla ese patrón. Pero sí, ambas construcciones son prácticamente lo mismo